# GLSL: does the time of computing depend on data value?

Tags: opengl, glsl, fft, gpgpu, data-transfer

Recently, I have been working on fft algorithm. I use glsl to count it faster.
The algorithm works fine, perfectly fine, but a result of time measuring is very strange:

If I do:

```
uniform sampler2D resultRe;
uniform sampler2D resultIm;
uniform int n;

void main(void)
{
      float v    = 2.0*n;
      float x    = gl_TexCoord[0].x - 0.5; 
      float y    = gl_TexCoord[0].y - 0.5;
      float re   = texture2D(resultRe, vec2(x/n,y/n)); 
     /* fft */   
      if(x<n*0.5){          
         gl_FragColor.r = re;//w1+w5;             
         gl_FragColor.g = re;}//w2+w6;}
     if(x>n*0.5-1.0){          
         gl_FragColor.r = re;//w1-w5;             
         gl_FragColor.g = re;}//w2-w6;} //range of re <0,255>, 
                                        //but if I multiply re by
                                        //-10000.0, the time of computing 
                                        //is almost the same.
}
```

The time of computing fft (by columns) is around **83ms** (log below).

- Creating fbo: 20.6251 ms
- Shader: 32.7854 ms
- Transfer GPU-CPU:29.8564 ms

But if I do (now, I return the true value of computing):

```
    uniform sampler2D resultRe;
    uniform sampler2D resultIm;
    uniform int n;

    void main(void)
    {
     float v    = 2.0*n;
     float x    = gl_TexCoord[0].x - 0.5; 
     float y    = gl_TexCoord[0].y - 0.5;
     float iy   = y/n; //for glsl purpose
     float ix   = x/n; 
     float w1=0.0, w2=0.0, w3=0.0, w4=0.0;
     float rad  = 0.0;
     float g = x; 
     if(g>n*0.5-1.0) x-=n*0.5;
     float rad2 = -dPI*g/n;

       /* fft here */   
      float w5 = (w3*cos(rad2)-w4*sin(rad2)); 
      float w6 = (w3*sin(rad2)+w4*cos(rad2)); 

       if(x<n*0.5){          
             gl_FragColor.r = w1+w5;             
             gl_FragColor.g = w2+w6;}
       if(x>n*0.5-1.0){          
             gl_FragColor.r = w1-w5;             
             gl_FragColor.g = w2-w6;}
    }
```

I must wait **~500ms** to get the result (log below).

- Creating fbo: 24.7944 ms
- Shader: 456.967 ms
- Transfer GPU-CPU: 28.6295ms

The question is: Why? The time of an execution doesn't depend on the value, does it? I can't come up with any idea.

To speed up data transfer, I'd tried use this: http://www.mathematik.uni-dortmund.de/~goeddeke/gpgpu/tutorial3.html#prep but I failed.

Time measuring: http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/opengl-short-tutorials/opengl-timer-query/

If you need more details, please ask.

Comment: where is your definition of w1-w6 in your second example? How does it look like?

Comment: From we're able to see so far, the second example will simply not compile.

Comment: @user: Are you really surprised the second shader executes much slower? You throw trigonometric functions in there and, in general, up the challenge for the ALU by adding at lot more arithmetic, while in your first example, the most expensive thing you do is probably the texture lookup.

Comment: ok... Let me put it in other way.
This both fragments are a fragment of the same shader.
But at first, I returned computing result and then I replaced one part (returning the value) of my shared by returning the 're' value. Is it clear now?
In both case there are cos ans sinus computed

Comment: Not only does it depend on data value, imagine sampling from random or distant texture coordinates—you totally mess with the GPU's ability to do texture caching—but it also depends on data _type_. You are using a bunch of scalars in your code and no vectors; you are stuck in CPU mentality.

Comment: Branching is very expensive in GLSL. In the first example the optimizer may be able to recognize that gl_FragColor always gets the same value, and thus eliminate the branch. (I'm not sure this can actually be done, but it seems likely.) What happens when you remove the if statements in you second example?

Comment: the if statements at the end of the code is only for fft algorithm (ex. the result for tab[x] = a+b; tab[x+length/2]=a-b) and if I removed it I would got a wrong result.

Answer (score 3):

The GLSL compiler (at least Nvidia/ATI) uses very aggressive optimizations. **If a value isn't used in the output, it simply gets removed**. This can even happen across shader stages. For example if a varying value doesn't contribute to the fragment shader output, the computation of the value is ignored in the vertex shader. I've found benchmarking shaders can be quite tricky since GLSL does many thing I find unexpected.

To force a value to be computed, do something simple with it. For example adding it to the colour (even scaled down a lot so it doesn't actually affect the colour much).

Looking at the shader binary can sometimes be helpful too: [glGetProgramBinary](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetProgramBinary.xml) (*if your GLSL compiler/driver includes the same kind of human readable assembly-like code mine does*)

Time certainly can change depending on the values. For example I believe matrix multiplies with zeros can be significantly faster (although I haven't tested this myself). I've also seen drastic changes in performance with very large numbers and especially invalid numbers (in these cases I've done something stupid allowing those values to exist in the first place).

Comment: Interesting. How can I use it? Where in the code should I do it?

Comment: Here's a page I found about it: http://www.nicolaslelong.fr/2011/08/about-using-glarbgetprogrambinary.html  For Nvidia at least, I currently don't need to hint `GL_PROGRAM_BINARY_RETRIEVABLE_HINT` but it is in the specs so don't expect portability if you don't. It spits out a bunch of binary data followed by what I can only assume is a plaintext representation of the assembly-like code which appears to do what the GLSL code does. Take it with a grain of salt but it's helped me before.

Comment: Thanks,I've found the page too. Maybe I don't understand sth, because it doesn't work: 
GLuint loadAndCompileShaders(const GLchar *d[],GLint Lenghts[],const GLchar *d1[],GLint Lenghts1[])
{/*here is creating and compiling shader*/
p=glCreateProgram();
glAttachShader(p,v);
glAttachShader(p,f);
GLint length;
glProgramParameteri(p,GL_PROGRAM_BINARY_RETRIEVABLE_HINT,GL_TRUE);
glGetProgramiv(p,GL_PROGRAM_BINARY_LENGTH,&length);
GLubyte *buffer = new GLubyte[length];      
glGetProgramBinary(p,length,0,0,buffer);
glProgramBinary(p,0,buffer,length); 
glLinkProgram(p);
glUseProgram(p);  
return p;}

Comment: `glProgramBinary` is used to upload the precompiled shader back into opengl. For some applications that have lots of shaders, compiling shaders on the first execution and then saving to disk for future use can be very useful. In this case you just want to write the binary to a file. Give the hint before glLinkProgram, then call glGetProgramBinary after glLinkProgram and write it to a file.

Comment: **+1** for suggesting the examination of compiled output. It need not spit out a text-based assembly language, however. It could be pure bytecode; sadly the OpenGL specification provides a mechanism for retrieving binary shaders and selection of formats, but not much else. I would love to see a standardized option for asking an implementation to explicitly output text-based disassembly (for debugging/low-level performance analysis) or bytecode (for compiled shader caching). For that matter, if you could use this to load assembly-language shaders directly and bypass GLSL, that would be heaven!

Comment: Agreed. Even apart from portability I'm sick of text editors complaining about the binary bit. I haven't got an ATI card that's compatible, does it produce anything useful?

Comment: I am working on my code right. I hope it would get me an improvement if I use glProgramBinagy. I'm new in openGl so I need some time. I've already have a binary version of shader program according to:http://www.geeks3d.com/20100727/opengl-4-1-allows-the-use-of-binary-shaders/ but still it does not working for me.

I couldn't work on that problem yesterday. thanks for your answering. If you have any other clue or pdf material worth to read please share.

Comment: I did the binary stuff but there is no improvement. The time of calculation is still the same.
Any other ideas?
Please remember that, there is only one shader and only values writting to gl_ColorFrag is different in those cases.

Comment: Looking at the output from glGetProgramBinary might be useful if the GLSL compiler includes some readable text (as my current Nvidia driver does) which would give you a lower level idea of what is actually happening in your shader - which parts get compiled out, which loops get unrolled etc. It won't make the shader run any faster and is only useful in deployment for improving application load times.